# Terms and style in sentences

Tags: grammar, writing-style

So on this sentence for example it's using (a) to expand on the main subject. It's exhaustive to read, but is it necessarilly wrong. What is the grammatical term for this usage or style (without knocking it). When we expand on the subject in this way.

Laura was trapped in a town like no other, a fantasy town, a town she felt trapped in, a town she no longer wanted to be, a place she could no longer escape, and 
she was staying in a hotel, a desolate, dry hotel, a hotel with patches on the sealing, a hotel with broken windows, a hotel she had to leave.

Comment: The technique of putting synonymous phrases together, with comma intonation, is called **Apposition**. The phrases are **Appositives**; they are said to be **In Apposition**. Normally one doesn't go this far, but it's not ungrammatical, merely dull.

Answer (score 1):

This technique, whether well or poorly executed, could be called **serial appositives with anadiplosis.**

[*Apposition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) occurs when one or more elements — almost always nouns/noun phrases — are placed next to another to define the first element. Without literary or rhetorical pretence, serial appositives can easily occur in unfiltered, unrehearsed speech, say, between guests at a wedding reception:

> My brother Josh, the banker from Philadelphia — you remember, the one who just bought the brownstone in Center City — is over by the punchbowl.

The proper name *Josh* and the noun phrases *the banker from Philadelphia* and *the one who just bought the brownstone in Center City* are all in apposition to *brother*.

[*Anadiplosis*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplosis), Gk. lit. ‘double folding back’, is a rhetorical device where a phrase- or sentence-final word is repeated in the next phrase/sentence, such as in this blurb for a book of children’s fiction:

> House of a Thousand Screams
> (Book #17 of Ghosts of Fear Street)
> By R.L. Stine
> For Ages: 8 - 12
> Uncle Solly has left Jill and Freddie’s family a [*house—a house*](http://www.simonandschuster.com/books/House-of-a-Thousand-Screams/R-L-Stine/Ghosts-of-Fear-Street/9781442487765) full of evil.

For better or worse, *house full of evil* is in apposition to *house*. The intended effect should be obvious; whether it has been achieved is, of course, a matter of opinion.

Put this all together and you get constructions such as these:

> I am a [*woman, a woman*](https://www.vice.com/en_uk/article/zmmqzj/the-problem-with-women-today) who has SLAMMED chaps as boring, grumpy slobs who cannot cook for themselves; *a woman* who has turned down self-identifying nice guys in favour of men who are horrible to me just for the thrill; *a woman* who propositions shy, retiring men who just want to go for walks.
>
> She had to see him as [*a man. A man*](https://books.google.de/books?id=UZvRAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&dq=%22a+man,+a+man+who%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirtO6S087aAhVoApoKHT7AD104FBDoAQg6MAQ) who could be distant but considerate. *A man* who didn't suffer fools gladly but still offered a second chance.  — Dara Girard, *Snowed in with the Doctor*, 2013, 101.
>
> “Parents, you should rejoice for having given birth to this type of [*a child. A child*](https://books.google.de/books?id=LckcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA264&dq=%22a+child,+a+child+who%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiirp7c1c7aAhUD26QKHWbADkgQ6AEITDAH) who prefers to fight it out with the oppressors rather than to be submerged in drunkenness, frustration and thuggery. *A child* who prefers to die from a bullet rather than to allow a poisonous education which relegates him and his parents to a position of perpetual subordination.” — Paul Nugent, *Africa since Independence*, 2012, 264.

Your example sentence, with two such constructions built on *town* and *hotel*, employs the identical technique. As the second citation suggests, writers of a certain class of popular fiction seem quite taken with the construction. Sometimes it can add gravitas, drama, or suspense, or, as in your example, dissolve into self-parody.